# Random values in database

Tags: java, mysql, excel, hibernate, apache-poi

I work on a spring mvc application with hibernate and mysql for data persistence and java as the backend. Use apache poi for excel parsing. I recently faced a strange issue.
I hit a specific endpoint in the controller. The service layer parses the excel sheet and store it a data structure. This structure is then mapped to my hibernate entity which in turn persists it to the db table. Everything was working fine. 
Recently a issue arose that on a specific day there was slow internet connectivity. The time taken for the transaction to complete was a little longer. The data persisted with the expected result but there were some random rows persisted as well.

The usecase is of a dependent dropdown in an enterprise application where the data to be set is provided by the user in the form of an xlsx upload.

As follows :
Expected result
[image]

Actual result
[image]

As can be seen in the images, there are some random rows with value 2,3,4,5,6. This is not there in the xlsx file used to upload the data.
The xlsx file used has data as follows:

[image]

In the logs, I found multiple entries of communication link failure. I tried to do an RCA but the code did not produce any anomaly.
Any hints as to what could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ticket_label_id` #130 a valid option?  You're saying that when you delete the data, and re-import from Excel, these mystery rows 2,3,4,5,6 show up again?  If so, I bet there is indeed some values **somewhere** on the Excel sheet.  Open each file in Excel and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> → `Options` → Turn on `Match entire cell contents` → Within `Workbook` → `Find What =` **`2`**.  Any hits?

If not, carefully **copy** only the raw data (ie., `A1:C15`) and then in a **new** workbook, Right Click → **Paste Values**.

Save the file with a **new name** if possible, and import that file.  I'd almost guarantee it will solve the issue.

Comment: yes ticket_label_id #130 is valid value. its a foreign key. I mentioned this happened randomly, this functionality has been behaving fine with this same xlsx. It is still behaving fine. This happened just twice yesterday and i am unable to reproduce even with the same xlsx. There is no data in the xlsx with 2,3,4,5,6 otherwise would have experienced the issue before. Would still verify with the method you mentioned.

Comment: If you had a connectivity problem (or even power problems, etc), an Excel file can become partially corrupt and do some weird stuff...  For example, maybe at row 50,000 column ZZ, in white (invisible) text, there are the values 2,3,4,5,6 that got mis-copied from another application that was open at the time.  (I've seen stuff like that happen.)  Ideally, an old backup from before this issue would be the easiest way to troubleshoot.  Other than that, it's best to start a fresh file to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I guess the excel file must have become corrupt due to low connectivity. Can't verify but thanks for the help

Comment: Yes it's confirmed. The file was getting corrupted during editing. Thanks @ashleendawg

Comment: @PrateekGupta  - You're welcome.  Excel gets pretty finicky when housing huge amounts of data.  Backup, backup, backup!   (and don't forget to *'Accept'* the answer if it was helpful.  :-)